# Oracle, casting varchar as numeric

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a really simple question which you guys who use oracle sql might answer really quickly.

Will this query work in oracle?

You guys can even run a similar query in your ORACLE DB to answer this one. I ask this question because we have to support multiple relational databases, and I don't have access to one from Oracle right now.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(OID AS numeric)) AS MAXOID
FROM FAKETABLE
```

Comment: Change numeric with number and it should work. I would though use the TO_NUMBER function. Syntax is the following : TO_NUMBER( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language] )

Comment: What is OID? What is its data type and what may some typical values look like?

Comment: You do have access to an Oracle database: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html

Comment: OID is a varchar(32), will try to use the oracle database on the cloud, thanks everyone for the help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle/PLSQL TO_NUMBER function converts a string to a number.

Syntax

The syntax for the TO_NUMBER function in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
TO_NUMBER( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language] )
```

Parameters or Arguments

string1
The string that will be converted to a number.

format_mask
Optional. This is the format that will be used to convert string1 to a number.

nls_language
Optional. This is the nls language used to convert string1 to a number.

For example:

Since the format_mask and nls_language parameters are optional, you can simply convert a text string to a numeric value as follows:

```
MAX(TO_NUMBER(OID)) AS MAXOID
```